# How to Check for HttpStatusCode.OK in GetResponse

Tags: c#, api, json.net, httpwebresponse

I was just wondering how to check if the HTTP status for okay before returning a value.

Here's the code snippet

```
var httpResponse = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(responseText);
            shorturl = data.shortLink;
    }
return shorturl;
```

Was thinking of something along the lines of

```
if responseText.Contains(HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

Or

```
if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
return shorturl;
```

Anything to point me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Cast your response to `HttpWebResponse` and access the `StatusCode` property.

Answer (score 2):

Internally  HttpStatusCode is enum

```
public enum HttpStatusCode
{
    ...
    Moved = 301,
    OK = 200,
    Redirect = 302,
    ...
}
```

Then

```
HttpStatusCode statusCode;

//your response code

statusCode = response.StatusCode;


if ((int)statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
return shorturl;
```

Comment: What does the response (response.StatusCode) refer to in this scenario?

Comment: [HttpWebResponse.StatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode?view=netframework-4.7.2) (which I guess the answerer means) does already have the proper enum type – no need casting it to int when you compare it to the same enum type anyway.